# Write and then read from the same file in Fortran

Tags: fortran

When I want write a code, with which I want to open a txt file, write a real number in it and pass the number to a variable in my code.

My code looks like:

```
open (unit = 22, file = x_file, status = 'old')
write(22, *) 1.2345

do while (ios == 0)
   read(22,*, iostat=ios) reader
end do

write(*,*) reader
```

After compiling this the variable "reader" got a very very small number (2.2460454138806765E-314). 
After deleting the line

```
write(22, *) 1.2345
```

and tipping the number directly in the txt file my variable "reader" become 1.2345. What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After writing the value to the file

```
write(22, *) 1.2345
```

the file is positioned at the end.

When reaching the end of file your statement

```
read(22,*, iostat=ios) reader
```

reads nothing, sets `ios` to the end of file non-zero value end proceeds further. **The value of `reader` is undefined!**

You cannot use the value of variables in the input list if iostat is non-zero.

Did you want:

```
open ( unit = 22, file = x_file, status = 'old' )

write(22, *) 1.2345

rewind(22)

read(22,*, iostat=ios) reader
if (ios/=0) stop

write(*,*) reader
```

?

Comment: I have an another question: How can i write my text with every write(31,*)  command in a new line?

Comment: It should do that. You can ask a new question in a new post with more details.